# Attempting to change cursor image with a .BAT file

Tags: windows, batch-file, cursor

I'm trying to change the default Windows cursor from the default arrow to a custom one. The thing is, I need to be able to do it from a batch file. One thing that worked before was to simply copy-replace the new cursor file to C:/Windows/Cursors, overriding the original aero_arrow.cur file, implemented like this:

```
copy %SystemRoot%\System32\TEMP\proj\aero_arrow.cur %SystemRoot%\Cursors\ /y
```

This overwrote aero_arrow.cur with the new aero_arrow.cur, changing the cursor.

However, this isn't actually working anymore, and I'm not sure why. Any ideas?

Comment: did you run your bat with admin privileges?

Comment: I did--right-clicked and selected "Run as Administrator".

Comment: `reg HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Control Panel\Cursors\Default /d "cursor_name" /f`  with this reg query you should be able to change the default cursor

Answer (score 0):

I've done this kind of thing before except with backgrounds. If you add start (program) below your

```
"copy %SystemRoot%\System32\TEMP\proj\aero_arrow.cur %SystemRoot%\Cursors\ /y"
```

Its hard to stop though if you don't use it through a USB.